# Placement ordering

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm using placements to implement m2m relations between pages and snippets, and I'ld like to order the results (aka the related snippetsà) in the page according to pre-defined "order". This order could be a date:

```
class NewsTopic(Page):
    intro = RicheText()
    ...

class NewsTopicPlacement(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage)
    news = ForeignKey(BewsTopicPage)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('News topic in home page')
        ordering = ('news__go_live_at',) # Does not work !

class HomePage(Page):
    intro = RichText()
    ...
```

I'ls like to order the results by news `go_live_at` dates, but I don't know how t implement that ? 
Thanks :

Comment: What you mean by `news__go_live_at` doesn't work?

Comment: I've an error while editing the snippet list in the HomePage : 
Internal Server Error: /admin/pages/4/edit/

    AttributeError at /admin/pages/4/edit/
    'NewsTopicPlacement' object has no attribute 'news__go_live_at'

Comment: I've also tryed to use:the combination:
`class NewsTopic(Page):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('go_livt_at', )
` and `
class NewsTopicPlacement(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = news
`
Following error: 
`
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'publications_homepagenewstopicplacement._order' in 'field list'")
`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to set a 'native' ordering through `NewsTopicPlacement`'s meta options, I'd suggest adding a method to `HomePage` to return the topics in the desired order:

```
class NewsTopicPlacement(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, related_name='news_topic_placements')
    news = ForeignKey(NewsTopicPage)


class HomePage(Page):
    ...
    def get_news_topics(self):
        return [
            placement.news
            for placement in self.news_topic_placements.order_by('news__go_live_at')
        ]
```

You can then write something like: `{% for news_topic in page.get_news_topics %}` in your homepage template to get the news topics in the appropriate order.